# oracle if 0, like if null (nvl)

Tags: oracle

oracle has a nice built in function for doing if null, however I want to do if = 0; is there a simple way to do this?

> nvl(instr(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5),' '),
>                 length(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5))))

This is going as a parameter to a substr function.

If `instr(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5),' ')` is `!= 0` then I want that value, otherwise I want the value of `length(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5))`

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll need to use [CASE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_case_sql_clause.htm)

e.g.

```
WHEN instr(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5),' ') != 0 THEN
  length(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5))
ELSE
   Some Default
END as foo
```

Comment: inside of the substring call?

Comment: `case  when instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bld') > 0 
      then substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bld')+5,
            case when instr(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bld')+5),' ') != 0
              instr(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bld')+5),' ')
              else
              length(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bld')+5))))
              end)
      else null end as BLDG_NM,`

Answer (score 24):

You can use `NVL(NULLIF(A,'0'), B)`

Answer (score 8):

I found both answers hard to read because of the extra verbiage from the original post. Summarizing Conrad and Craig's answers:

To replicate nvl(A,B) but for 0 instead of null, you can do:

```
WHEN A != 0 THEN
  A
ELSE
  B
END
```

or Craig's more compact (but harder for others to read):

```
NVL(NULLIF(A,0),B)
```

I think that the following would also work:

```
DECODE(A,0,B,A)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could technically do this with less typing as:

```
nvl(
    nullif(instr(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5),' '),0),
    length(substr(ovrflo_adrs_info,instr(ovrflo_adrs_info,'bldg')+5))
)
```

However, I would typically side with Conrad and advise you to use CASE so it is easier to tell what the intent of the code is for future maintenance.

Comment: I like the `nullif` function though. I'll have to keep that in mind for future use...